# Союзы - союзные слова

Tags: союзы

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста! В предложении "Чем больше кошку гладишь, тем больше она горб подымает" cлово "тем" как член предложения и схема предложения.

Answer (score 4):

Чем...тем - двойной союз, самостоятельным членом предложения не является, присоединяет придаточное сравнительное к главному.

(чем =),[тем - =].